# Understanding tpcdump -d option

Tags: linux, tcpdump

I'm new to the forum, so apologies if I'm breaking any rules here (feel free to correct and/or re-direct)

That said: I'm trying to understand what the "-d" option does in tpcdump
(i.e. `tcpdump -i any -d`)

Running the example command above, it's clear that the output is different than without -d, but I'm not understanding the output or its purpose

The man page states

> "Dump the compiled packet-matching code in a human readable form to standard output and stop."

but I'm having trouble parsing the meaning - What does it mean by packet-matching code? And what are some of the purposes of using this output?

Many thanks for any responses

Answer (score 1):

When you use a capture filter with tcpdump like `tcpdump -i <any> tcp port 443`, you are filtering *out* packets that are not TCP packets or that aren't sent on port 443. But how, you ask, does tcpdump know how to do this?

Packet-matching code here refers to [BPF](https://biot.com/capstats/bpf.html) (Berkeley Packet Filter) syntax code. In other words, what does `tcp port 443` break down into at a lower level? If we run `tcpdump -i <any> tcp port 443`, we can see:

```sh
$ tcpdump -i en0 -d tcp port 443
(000) ldh      [12]
(001) jeq      #0x86dd          jt 2    jf 8
(002) ldb      [20]
(003) jeq      #0x6             jt 4    jf 19
(004) ldh      [54]
(005) jeq      #0x1bb           jt 18   jf 6
(006) ldh      [56]
(007) jeq      #0x1bb           jt 18   jf 19
(008) jeq      #0x800           jt 9    jf 19
(009) ldb      [23]
(010) jeq      #0x6             jt 11   jf 19
(011) ldh      [20]
(012) jset     #0x1fff          jt 19   jf 13
(013) ldxb     4*([14]&0xf)
(014) ldh      [x + 14]
(015) jeq      #0x1bb           jt 18   jf 16
(016) ldh      [x + 16]
(017) jeq      #0x1bb           jt 18   jf 19
(018) ret      #262144
(019) ret      #0
```

For an information about what people use `tcpdump -d` for, there are articles [on](https://comaware.wordpress.com/2013/12/21/tcpdump-studying-the-packet-matching-code-and-vlan-primitive/) [it](https://taosecurity.blogspot.com/2004/09/understanding-tcpdumps-d-option-have.html). For a thorough breakdown of how BPF code works, tshark.dev has an [article](https://tshark.dev/packetcraft/arcana/bpf_instructions/) on it.

Comment: If you'd like more information and background on libpcap and BFP, then I would highly recommend the Sharkfest '11 Keynote presented by Steve McCanne, the BPF and pcap creator, titled "The Architecture and Optimization Methodology of the libpcap Packet Capture Library".  You can find the Keynote Video and Presentation material here: https://sharkfestus.wireshark.org/sharkfest.11/.  Steve is now the Coding CEO at Brim: https://www.brimsecurity.com/team/